# Why activemq web console does not appear on all browsers,only firefox

Tags: java, windows, activemq-classic

i am new about activemq. I downloaded it from its web site and installed on windows. After starting it,when i write "http://localhost:8161/admin", only i see web console on Firefox. Chrome and IE didnt work.Why ?

Comment: what version of AMQ are you using?  it works fine for me in FF, Chrome and Safari (on Mac)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I just discovered if there's an open authentication prompt session (i.e. a browser tab opened at `http://localhost:8161/admin` prompting for authentication), until it is closed, any other session will not go through.